# Message Box Error when executing program outside of IDLE that doesn't occur when executing in IDLE in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

I have a bit of code that creates a message box when a button is pressed, this works with no problems when i run my program in IDLE but if i run the program outside of IDLE will bring up an error "name 'messagebox' is not defined" Why does this only happen when executing outside of IDLE?

```
def Reset():
    ResetMess = messagebox.askyesno("Confirm Reset", "Are you sure?")
```

Comment: I have imported tkinter by the way, sorry forgot to say earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside IDLE, messagebox has to be imported explicitly

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Comment: Thanks, glad it was something as simple as that! @sprtnbst